# GPO WMI filter not excluding computers

Tags: active-directory, group-policy, wmi, organizational-unit

I have a GPO modifying user and computer configuration. On this GPO a WMI filter based on the hostname exclude some of the computers.

```
select Name from Win32_ComputerSystem where (Name <> "comp1-*")
select Name from Win32_ComputerSystem where (Name <> "comp2-*")
select Name from Win32_ComputerSystem where (Name <> "comp3-*")
```

Each line is a separate request in the filter.

GPO is linked to a parent OU and the security filtering is left to the "Authenticated users" as default.

My GPO is still applied on all computers of the parent and the sub OU.

Any ideas ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The WMI query is invalid.  You should test this using wbemtest.exe or WMICodeCreator before linking it to a GPO.

Here is an example of a working query:

```
SELECT NAME FROM Win32_ComputerSystem WHERE NOT (Name LIKE 'comp1-%')
```